# Responsive Menu & Shopping Cart Icons squished when viewing on mobile device

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I am working on a responsive site (http://tinyurl.com/bvcqmhg), and the icons for the shopping cart and responsive menu are squished when viewed on my iPhone (and maybe other mobile devices). The icons are png files and they are placed with the css background property. Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set a width or height on them. That's what I'd try first.